# EF Core 3.0 : Multiple navigation properties in an entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0

Here are the 2 entities I have defined and I am using EF Core 3.0.
Whenever I try to create a new migration, I keep getting an error saying can not have the same navigation property in multiple relationships.

Me being a noob in EF Core, any pointers in resolving this issue would be very helpful.

```
public class Event
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public EventContext StartContext { get; set; }
        
        public EventContext EndContext { get; set; } 
        public Guid CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public Guid UpdatedBy { get; set; }
        
    }

    public class EventContext
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public Guid EventId { get; set; } //fk
        public Event Event { get; set; }
        public DateTime ApplicableDate { get; set; }        
    }
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the model creation/migration code to your question as well. Also add the full complete error message you get.

Comment: Oh well, seems that you have a  circular reference ... Event has reference to EventContext and same goes for EventContext which holds a reference to the Event
 CHanging the ladder to just have the event id referenced should do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the EF Core tools will tell you:

```
Cannot create a relationship between 'Event.EndContext' and 'EventContext.Event', because there already is a relationship between 'Event.StartContext' and 'EventContext.Event'. Navigation properties can only participate in a single relationship.
```

There are two simple solutions to this issue:

#### Use two navigation properties on the `EventContext` type

If you actually need the navigation property on `EventContext` and not just on `Event`, then the following will work:

```cs
public class Event
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public Guid UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    
    public EventContext StartContext { get; set; }
    public EventContext EndContext { get; set; }
}

public class EventContext
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid EventId { get; set; }
    public DateTime ApplicableDate { get; set; }
    
    // One navigation property for each corresponding navigation property on `Event`.
    public Event StartContextEvent { get; set; }
    public Event EndContextEvent { get; set; }
}

public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Event> Events { get; set; }
    public DbSet<EventContext> EventContexts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Event>(
            entity =>
            {
                entity.HasOne(e => e.StartContext)
                    .WithOne(e => e.StartContextEvent)
                    .HasForeignKey<EventContext>(e => e.EventId);

                entity.HasOne(e => e.EndContext)
                    .WithOne(e => e.EndContextEvent)
                    .HasForeignKey<EventContext>(e => e.EventId);
            });
    }
}
```

#### Use a one-way navigation property

If you can live without the navigation property on `EventContext` and are happy to just use the one on `Event`, then just remove it from `EventContext` and the following will work for you as well:

```cs
public class Event
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public Guid UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    
    public EventContext StartContext { get; set; }
    public EventContext EndContext { get; set; }
}

public class EventContext
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid EventId { get; set; }
    public DateTime ApplicableDate { get; set; }
}

public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Event> Events { get; set; }
    public DbSet<EventContext> EventContexts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Event>(
            entity =>
            {
                entity.HasOne(e => e.StartContext)
                    .WithOne()
                    .HasForeignKey<EventContext>(e => e.EventId);

                entity.HasOne(e => e.EndContext)
                    .WithOne()
                    .HasForeignKey<EventContext>(e => e.EventId);
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you lauxjpn.
As per the suggestion you gave, I removed the navigation property "Event" in Event Context.

Comment: I was thinking of an alternative as below, please let me know your views on it
`public class Event
{ 
   ...other props
    public ICollection<EventContext> EventContexts { get; set; }
}

public enum EventCotextType
{
    Start =0,
    End = 1
}
public class EventContext
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid EventId { get; set; }
    public EventContextType EventContextType { get; set; }
    public DateTime ApplicableDate { get; set; }
}`

Comment: Sure, if that works for you you can go this route as well. But in case an `Event` can only have one `EventContext` per `EventContextType` (which I assume is the case), then you would want to drop the `EventContext.Id` property and define its primary key as `.HasKey(e => new {e.EventId, e.EventContextType})` instead, to enforce this behavior.

Comment: As per you, which approach would be more performant?

Comment: There should be no real difference in performance. Its probably more a question of what will be easier to use in the code. If you expect there to be a lot more `EventContext` types in the future than the 2 you are using now, then your approach is probably better. If you expect there to be only the 2 you are using now, then I would keep using the `StartContext ` and `EndContext` properties, because your queries will be much easier to read and maintain.